Stop absolutely positioned ::before content from allowing a line break
In this snippet, the number 5 appears in the margin to the left of the word “incididunt”, and a blue mark appears inside the word, as desired.
But if the window is just the right width, the word breaks across two lines at the blue mark.
Using just CSS (and not wrapping the word inside a new span), can I keep “incididunt” together and keep the line from breaking?
I tried adding white-space:nowrap to .note and to .note::before. Neither helped. I see a few related questions on SO but all more complicated than this and without solutions.


body {margin-left:30px; position:relative}

.note {
  border-left:2px solid blue;
}
.note::before {
  content:"5";
  position:absolute;
  left:-25px;
}
<body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor inci<span class="note"></span>didunt</body>




I'm not clear on what problem you are trying to solve. If you don't want the word to break, wrap it in a span and nowrap it.

https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExzxwpQ

I have a bunch of HTML files with this problem, so I am looking for a CSS solution that does not require changing the HTML. Semantically also, I don’t like tweaking the HTML for a formatting problem like this.

I fixed the ::after to ::before to match the title.

Early close votes might have been justified, but imho this question is now clear and also quite interesting, so I'm suggesting we keep it open. I can't think of a solution though :-(

It's not a formatting problem per se, you've already broken the work by adding the span, as such you can't stop it breaking without adding nowrap somewhere and wrapping the word in a span does that.

On my system, the word breaks in Chrome but not in Safari. The breakage is not caused by the pseudo-element, it’s caused by the <span> tag. What is the purpose of the blue mark, and why would you want it positioned in the middle of a word?

@BrettDonald the breakage does seem to be caused by the position absolute of the pseudo element. When I removed that there was no breakage (at least on Chrome/Edge Windows10).

@BrettDonald: The text is copied from a book. The marginal number is a page number in that book. The vertical bar indicates where exactly the page break occurred.

I see that the word does not break in Firefox (on Windows). It does break on Edge (which, like Chrome, uses Chromium). I’d say it is a bug. I haven’t thought of a semantic reason that absolute positioning should be a break-able event. I have seen other posts on SO that are at root this same issue.

@jpm yes, I agree.
